# symfony + doctrine + inheritance, how to make them work?

Tags: php, inheritance, symfony1, doctrine

I am beginning to work with Symfony, I've found some documentation about inheritance. But also found [this discouraging article](http://geekblog.over-blog.com/article-26412530.html), which make me doubt if Doctrine handles inheritance any good at all...

**Has anyone find a smart solution for inheritance in Symfony+Doctrine?**

As an example, I have already structured the database something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `poster` (
  `poster_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`poster_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`poster_id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `real_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `user_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `poster` (`poster_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

From that, Doctrine generated this "schema.yml":

```
Poster:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: poster
  columns:
    poster_id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    user_name:
      type: string(50)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
  relations:
    Post:
      local: poster_id
      foreign: poster_id
      type: many
    User:
      local: poster_id
      foreign: user_id
      type: many
    Version:
      local: poster_id
      foreign: poster_id
      type: many
User:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: user
  columns:
    user_id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: false
    real_name:
      type: string(50)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
  relations:
    Poster:
      local: user_id
      foreign: poster_id
      type: one
```

User creation for this structure with Doctrine auto-generated forms does not work.

Any clue will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm confused as to how you want to apply inheritance based on the above data (your original SQL doesn't correlate with the .yml produced).  Can you elaborate as to what you're trying to do?

Comment: Thanks for answering.

Well, it should correlate, since it was generated with Doctrine. I did crop it to focus on the issue. I just find Poster table's relations weird, because those are external FK from other tables to Poster table...

I'm just trying to extend Poster with User, that's why I made user_id a FK of poser_id. Please tell me if I need to be more specific.

Comment: Mmm I see now (the 'Version' stuff was confusing me).  It might be easier if you start with writing the schema in .yml first - I can't see why Doctrine would generate those other relationships unless you are auto-generating from a database that already has FKs in place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After several months working on a project using both column aggregation and concrete inheritance I can only say one thing : stay away from concrete inheritance ! Really.

Let's say you have 3 table : Media and Video/Audio which inherits from Media. You would expect to be able to do something like :

```
Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->from('Media m')
    ->execute();
```

Well it won't work with concrete inheritance. It's just worthless and has almost no practical use, except for model inheriting methods.

On the other hand, with column aggregation, the Media table will have a "type" column automagically added, and will enable you to things such as :

```
Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->from('Video v')
    ->execute();
```

Which will return a Video object collection. But you could also do this :

```
Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->from('Media m')
    ->execute();
```

And you will get a mixed result of Video and Audio objects.

Anyway you should check the [doctrine documentation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/inheritance/en).
But be careful as inheritance and doctrine can rapidly become troublesome.

Comment: Thanks for the piece of advice, but I really needed a solution to start developing a project and I managed to make it work somehow. 
The problem is that column aggregation handles or objects on a single supertable and I think that is bad database design.
I am really disappointed of how poorly Doctrine handles inheritance at database level. I saw concrete inheritance as a incomplete way to go, so I generated the model based on it and then modified the tables implementation. It works for now, let's see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

A solution to separate 'Video' data from say 'Audio' data but still use the same table to store 'Media' is as follows:

```
Media:
  columns:
    name: { type: string(255), notnull: true }
    description: { type: text }

Video:
  inheritance:
    type: column_aggregation
    keyField: type
    keyValue: video

Audio:
  inheritance:
    type: column_aggregation
    keyField: type
    keyValue: audio

VideoData:
  columns:
    resolution_x: { type: integer, notnull: true }
    resolution_y: { type: integer, notnull: true }
  relations:
    Video: { foreignAlias: Data, onDelete: CASCADE }

AudioData:
  columns:
    sample_rate: { type: integer, notnull: true }
  relations:
    Audio: { foreignAlias: Data, onDelete: CASCADE }
```

Something like that... That way you can store all your 'Media' in one table and fetch it as mentioned above by DuoSRX and still not have irrelevant data in that table. Sure you have to join it, but with indexed foreign keys that should not be a performance hit at all.